# Extra single quotes added for a double quote expression in jenkins configuration shell

Tags: bash, shell, unix, jenkins, sh

I am new to bash script. I am running a bash script. I want that the expression to be evaluated as "value". But when I execute that in jenkins, I am getting '"value"'. Not sure if this is something to do with jenkins or shell script.
Below is the sample code :

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
Date1=${date}
dql="\"" #double quote literal
Date1=$dql$Date1$dql 
echo $Date1 #"2018-06-21"
expr=$( date is $Date1) # output is ´"2018-06-21"´
```

the value I am getting surrounded by single quote. But I have to only the double quoted value. Can you help me to fix/identify issue.

---

Editing to show the original script

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

mydate=`date`              # Save the output of date command into the variable mydate

dquote="\""                # Save the dbl-quote character into the variable dquote

mydate=""${dquote}""${mydate}""${dquote}""     # Construct a string that encases the date with dbl-quotes



eval myexp=$mydate



echo $mydate

echo date is "${mydate}"

#echo -e "\042"



output :





++ date

+ mydate='Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018'

+ dquote='"'

+ mydate='"Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018"'

+ eval 'myexp="Sun' Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC '2018"'

++ myexp='Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018'

+ echo '"Sun' Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC '2018"'

"Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018"

+ echo date is '"Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018"'

date is "Sun Jun 24 10:04:12 UTC 2018"
```

if you see the last but one line.. the expression is giving  single quote and then double quotes, that is my problem. During run time,the same argument is being passed to another script where it is getting single quote which inturn is failing. However, the echo output is as expected which has only double quotes, but run time output has extra single quotes. Hope I am clear this time. I could not post actual code as it is compliance related issue.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are enclosing `Date1` in double-quotes?

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear with my question. my issue here is not with date. actually the expr has other values apart from date. There will be other script to which this expr will be passed as argument. that format it expects is something like [date is "2018-06-21" ........]. my question is if I have value say Date1 (it can be any type) , I want double quotes to that value after expression is evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear to me.

You store the date into a Bash shell variable.  You want to pass this variable to another program (I'm guessing that's what you mean when you say 'execute that in Jenkins') but the value of the variable has an extra set of quotes, specifically outer single quotes, which you do not want.  I'm guessing you are asking how to prevent the outer single quotes.

Did I understand you correctly?

Does the following similar code help?

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate=`date`              # Save the output of date command into the variable mydate
dquote="\""                # Save the dbl-quote character into the variable dquote
mydate="${dquote}${mydate}${dquote}"     # Construct a string that encases the date with dbl-quotes 
echo date is [$mydate]     # Output is:  date is ["Wed Jun 20 22:52:46 EDT 2018"]
```

I see your edited question and its honestly still unclear to me.  I'm guessing you want to save a variable that has embedded spaces as a complete string in order to pass to another script which needs to process that string.  Hopefully this is accurate.

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mydate="\"`date`\""
echo date is [$mydate]

% date is ["Mon Jun 25 20:38:00 EDT 2018"]
```

Note I'm using [] as delimiters only to avoid confusion with quotes; I could have used any other character as a delimiter.  Now the $mydate variable contains double quotes.

Comment: I should have written more clearly. I added comment below the question. I want the double quotes to a value after the expression is evaluated.

Comment: It is still unclear to me.  Your sentence "I want the double quotes to a value after the expression is evaluated" is a bit ambiguous to me.  Are you asking how to pass a value from one shell script to another program and make sure the double-quotes are passed as well?

Comment: I have edited the question posted almost the actual code issue that I am facing. Hope I am clear this time

Answer (score 0):

Based on your clarifying comment, here's the code you can try:

```
$ date="2018-06-21"
$ expr="date is \"${date}\""
$ echo $expr
date is "2018-06-21"
```

In this code, `expr` will contain `date is "2018-06-21"`, where the date value is in double-quotes as you expect.

Comment: thank you. 
I tried this. $ set -x

$ date="2018-06-21"
+ date=2018-06-21

$ expr="date is \"${date}\""
+ expr='date is "2018-06-21"'

$ expr1="${expr}"
+ expr1='date is "2018-06-21"'

if you see above, both expr and expr1 are having single quote surrounded values. I would not need the single quote here. when I execute the actual script, I am getting single quoted value. am I missing something here ?

Comment: @user12 Is that not how you want it?

Comment: I have edited and posted the question with almost actual script. can you please have a look and see if you can help me ?